# Python Requests Module Doesn't Fetch All The Elements It Ought To

Tags: python, python-requests, hidden

This piece of code works properly

```
from lxml import html
import requests
page = requests.get(c)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
link = tree.xpath('//script/text()')
```

But it doesn't fetch the whole content. Like it is hidden or something.

I can see this is the case because the next thing I do is this

```
print len(link)
```

and it returns nine (9)

I then go to the page, which is the string c, above in the code. I go to the source (view-source:) with mozilla. And I hit ctr+f and I write  `<script` with a space in the end.

It returns me thirty three (33) matches. The one I want cannot be fetched.

What's happening? I can't understand. Am I blocked or something? How can I bypass this and make requests module see what mozilla is seeing?

Comment: `requests` doesn't embed a javascript engine with a dom representation. If anything in your page is generated by js browser-side (including dynamic inclusion of other scripts - this is a common browser-side pattern), you obviously won't find it in `request`'s response.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm wrong, but I just want an html tag. I don't want the content. The content inside the script is a base 64 string that firefox can run into a javascript function and produce content. I don't care about this. I don't want the rendered html, I want the unrendered html. Are you talking about the rendered javacrpit? I can render it myself. But I can't fetch it... `<script>` is an html tag. I see it without having it rendered. Why doesn't `requests` see it?

Comment: Please re-read my comment: __dynamically generating scripts tags__ from browser-side js is a common pattern.

Answer (score 0):

If you try

```
tree.xpath('//script')
```

I hope you will get 33 matches.

On your page only nine  elements contain something between the opening and closing tags.

Comment: Now they are more, not 33, but If I remove the `text()` it returns me a list with 15 things that say something like this "<Element script at 0xb6d9889c>". Can't `str()` into strings. How can I translate this into a string? Sorry for the noobing, I tried something with string() and etree, but couldn't find the proper syntax as of yet.

Comment: Found it. Having imported the etree module from lxml,  I can simply `tostring()` the [14] element of the list. But the problem remains. It doesn't fetch all sctript tags... the list has only 15 items...

Comment: Just guessing: maybe you have iframes on your page?

Comment: It has some iframes, but the tags i want are not inside iframes. Look: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-MwmXeirbcGU/WgrsmBTKwdI/AAAAAAAAABc/SxepDReNfNIye2sp3ihrP6EzcqW_UUBvQCLcBGAs/s1600/151066536958107.png I tried the parent div tags and I cannot find them too. I did it yesterday and not only fetched the base 64 string, but I worte a script that decodes it too and edits it then, and it run. I'm strarting to think that the site did something to block me. I know it's crazy...